# How to fix the div while scrolling using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, css

I am facing problem to fix a div when scrolling, actually I have the fix the div at right of the page below header content, it is fixed but when we scroll up it is placed above the header content.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  function fixDiv() {
    var $cache = $('#getFixed');
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100)
      $cache.css({
        'position': 'fixed',
        'top': '0'
      });
    else
      $cache.css({
        'position': 'static'
      });
  }
  
  $(window).scroll(fixDiv);
  fixDiv();
});
```

```css
#getFixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 5%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-2 ord-3 npd visible-lg">
  <div id="getFixed">
    <div class="prfsdbg">
      <div class="prfasdr text-center"></div>
      <div class="ntfsnt">rerkjehglrjgnb</div>
      <p class="prsntxt">
        Upgradasfddddddddddddddddddddd<br> Starting at just $15
      </p>
      <div class="text-center">
        <a href="#" type="button" class="ntfbtn     btsm">Viewplans</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It isn't a good idea to use jQuery and Angular together..

Comment: @ tanmay ya i know I need in jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#getFixed{
  position: fixed;
}
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kvx9w4s3/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `z-index` in CSS to solve this problem. For example: if you wanna show header on top then use `z-index: 2;` for header  and `z-index: 1;` for that div. for more: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp